# Programmatically Listing the Checked off Project References in VBA?

Tags: vba, dependencies, ms-office

Is it possible to get a list of included Project References in VBA?

I'd like to be able to write them out to a file or text, and compare them to another set.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=list+of+included+Project+References

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify...this is for vba for office.

Comment: Googling your question title get hits which look to answer your question.

Comment: Google SERPs are location based.  And anyway I wouldn't have asked the question if I found an answer out there.

Comment: OK here's the first hit: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0daa06d-c6ac-4582-afc9-92df27ab98d3/how-to-get-programmatically-a-list-of-all-available-references-of-a-vba-project?forum=isvvba

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Reference the VBIDE API and authorise VBA to programmatically access that API (there's a checkbox for it in macro security settings) - note that this API allows you to write VBA code that can alter the code in this or any other VBA project in the VBE.

You'll want to access the `VBProject` object you're interested in, and then iterate its `References`.

```
Dim myProject As VBProject
Set myProject = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject

Dim library As Reference
For Each library In myProject.References
    Debug.Print library.Name
Next
```

That will include the VBA standard library, stdole, the object model for the host application you're in, MSForms if your project has `UserForm` objects, and any other COM library your project might reference. If the project references other VBA projects, they will be there too; you can tell a referenced VBA project from a COM type library by verifying whether the reference has a `Guid` (only a registered COM type library would have a GUID).